# How to aggregate data from CSV file to store into linked list of objects in Java

Tags: java

I have to read in a CSV file (of length 5,000ish) with data about hotels that looks like:

```
Level, Room No., Room Tier, Hotel Member, Extras, Smoking, Lastname, Firstname, Rate
3, 301, Deluxe, N, N, Y, SMITH, John, 300
3, 302, Standard, Y, N, N, CAHILL, Patricia, 200
4, 401, Standard, N, Y, N, BUCKNELL, Christopher, 200
4, 402, Premier, Y, Y, N, GUNNING, Robert, 500
```

My task is to use Linked Lists (which I must implement myself) and sum the total nightly rate of each level. The `Level` object goes into a linked list.

Right now I have a `Level` object that holds the details about the Level and a linked list of `Room` objects. Which store everything else in the CSV row.

The Level class also has a method to construct a new Room object and add it to the "rooms" Linked List.

```
public class Level
{
    private int levelNum; 

    private LinkedList rooms;

    public Level(int inLevelNum)
    {
        levelNum = inLevelNum; 

        rooms = new LinkedList(); 
    }
    ...
}
```

**The issue I have is figuring out how to aggregate the CSV rows. Combining the floors into one object and then using the `addRoom` method. Without adding duplicate Level objects into the list.**

e.g. from that CSV snippet I want to create 2 level objects, Level 3 and 4.

Note, I'm not allowed to use any Java implementation of any Data Structure. It all must be my Implementation. What I have implemented so far is just Linked Lists, Trees, Stacks and Queues.

Sorry if this didn't make sense. I'm also new to asking on Stack Overflow, please correct me on anything I should've done! Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a "level number" field inside a room class and not as a separate class? Then you could simply filter out all rooms where level == x and then do something.

Comment: @Amongalen I would love to as that's much easier, but I'm not sure how figure out what the level numbers are later as they get mixed up to random numbers 3 digits long. Like random levels 221-500.

Comment: You avoid adding duplicate `Level` objects to the list by first searching the list using the level value from the CSV file. Create an `addRoom` method in the `Level` class and also add a `totalRate` member to the class and then add the rate of the room `totalRate` in the `addRoom` method, then everything is properly calculated once all rows has been read and all rooms added.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `first searching the list using the level value from the CSV file` does this mean that I go level by level? 

and when do I call addRoom in the Level class?

Comment: I assume you have a search method in your `LinkedList` class but otherwise you need to add one but it could be a simple method that loops through all nodes until it finds one that matches. If the search finds a `Level` object then call addRoom on that object, otherwise create a new object and add it to the list and call addRoom on that instead.